# Changing the state in reactJs parent is not changing the props in react child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a Parent React Component and which have 3 Child components i am changing the state in parent component but changing the state in parent is not changing the props in child components.I am passing the state from parent to child components but the props are not changing inside the child components.

My parent component

```
class Parent extends Component {

    state = {
        menuCategoryId:'',
    }
    handelOnClickRefundMenu = () => {
        this.setState({menuCategoryId:''});
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <FoodMenu 
                    menuCategories={menuCategories} 
                    {...this.state}
                />
        )
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

Child 1 Component

```
class FoodMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <MenuCategories 
                    MenuCategories={menuCategories.MenuCategories}
                    selectedMenuCategoryId={this.props.menuCategoryId}
                />

        );
    }
}

export default Child1;
```

Child 2 component

```
class MenuCategories extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const MenuCategories = this.props.MenuCategories;
        const selectedMenuCategoryId = this.props.selectedMenuCategoryId;
        const renderCategories = (MenuCategories) => (
            MenuCategories ? 
                MenuCategories.map(card=>(
                    <MenuCategory
                        key={card._id}
                        {...card}
                        handleOnClickMenuCategory={this.props.handleOnClickMenuCategory}
                        selectedMenuCategoryId={this.props.selectedMenuCategoryId}
                        // propData={...this.props}
                    />
                ))
            :null
        )
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div id="" className="food-menus-menu w-100">
                    <div className="row">
                    <OwlCarousel
                        className="owl-theme"
                        loop={true}
                        items={9}
                        autoplay={false}
                        autoplayTimeout={3000}
                        autoplayHoverPause={false}
                        nav={true}
                        navElement={'div'}
                        navText={[`<img src=${seventheenPng}>`,`<img src=${eitheenPng}>`]}
                        dots={false}
                        responsive={{
                            0:{
                                items:4
                            },
                            600:{
                                items:3
                            },
                            1000:{
                                items:7
                            }
                        }}
                    >

                            {MenuCategories ?
                                MenuCategories.length === 0 ?
                                    <div className="no_result">
                                        Sorry, no results
                                    </div>
                                :null
                            :null}
                            { renderCategories(MenuCategories)}

                        </OwlCarousel>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </Fragment>
        )
    }
};

export default MenuCategories;
```

Child 3 Component

```
class MenuCategory extends Component {
    render() {

        const props = this.props;
        console.log('The values of the props are not changing here')
        console.log(props.selectedMenuCategoryId)
        return (
            <div className={`colCategory item`} onClick={()=>props.handleOnClickMenuCategory(props)}>
                <button
                    className={`btn btn-primary w-100 py-2 d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center ${props.selectedMenuCategoryId ===  props._id ? 'activeMenuCategory' : ''}`}>
                    {props.name}
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MenuCategory;
```

The value of props **"props.selectedMenuCategoryId"** in my last component which is inside the **Map function** **MenuCategory** is not changing when i change the state in my **Parent Class function** **handelOnClickRefundMenu**

The Map function is inside Child Component 2 **MenuCategories** .

Kindly help me on this please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit you question properly. I see you are rendering a FoodMenu component in your parent component, but i dont see any child component name FoodMenu. Also dont pass the props with same name as component's name. Always try to use a different name, it makes the code easier to read.

Comment: @HarshitAgarwal i have edited my Class Name Food Menu sorry for confusion kindly let me know is their anything else you want me to do.

Comment: I dont think the way you are passing props to foodMenu from parentComponent is right.  What exactly do you want to pass to foodmenu from parent?

Comment: I want to pass the menuCategoryId state from the parent to my last child component MenuCategory .

Comment: ok. so a little theory first will give you the code a little later. OK onto the answer. So when you pass props using a value from state variable to a child component and then if the state changes. Then the child component's props will get updated. But here is a trick. Even though your props are getting updated, the component will not re render. Hence u might not be able to see the change directly.

Comment: For your component to re-render it needs a state update,hence you will have to use a react lifecycle method called componentWillRecieveProps. This method gets called when you component's props change. So using this method you can update your child component state which will re render the component and hence resolve your problem. Read about componentWillRecieveProps in react documentation

Comment: Thanks for explaining this but can you please adjust this in the my code because i new to react it will be really helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193524/discussion-between-harshit-agarwal-and-usama).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the answers about forcing re-renders using lifecycle methods are wrong. If you pass the props down correctly and they change, your child components should re-render automatically.

To demonstrate this, [here's a quick'n'dirty sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-faraday-sdu07) that has a parent and two children that passes a prop down as you require.

I don't know exactly what's wrong with your code (a self-contained example that we can run and debug would help here), but I suggest paring it back to a simpler case that you can get working and then build up from there.

eta: Are you sure the problem isn't to do with your click handler? You're not passing it in to FoodMenu or MenuCategories.

Comment: Will i have debugged the code using console.logs i am getting the props changed till Child 2 component but i am not getting the props change value in Child 3 component which is MenuCategory .

Comment: The MenuCategory component is being called inside a Map Function which loops through a array of Menu Categories. Then i am calling the MenuCategory Component inside it...

Comment: As I said, I suggest re-creating your example in a self-contained codesandbox or similar.

Comment: The problem is not with click handler the problem is with Map function.

Comment: The props are not being changed inside the map function.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using map - I've updated the sandbox to include one. It still works.

Comment: Yes it is working in the sandbox but it is not working on my side can you please suggest some debugging which can help me on this issue ...?

Comment: I suggest forking my sandbox, then changing it slowly to look more like yours in steps.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you naming your prop and variables the same as your component? It’s really hard to read and is probably causing confusion as to whether you’re referencing the component or the prop/variable. Use camel case

Naming your prop MenuCategories inside the component MenuCategories is not only bad practice, but could solve the issue if named menuCategories instead.